# Calculated field based on sum and count of other field

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a dataset like this:

```
Segment   Organisation name   nr of visitors
A         {name}              3
A         {name}              7            
B         {name}              20                  
B         {name}              20
B         {name}              10
B         {name}              10
C         {name}              8
C         {name}              8
C         {name}              8
C         {name}              6
```

I have a pivot table with three columns, where values are displayed as percentage:

```
Segment   Count of organisations   Sum of visitors
A         20%                      10%
B         40%                      60%
C         40%                      30%
```

I want to add a third column which does sum of visitors% divided by count of org.%.

```
Segment   Count of organisations   Sum of visitors   Leverage
A         20%                      10%               0.5        
B         40%                      60%               1.5
C         40%                      30%               0.75
```

Using a calculated field I can't seem to do this. Is it possible to have this as a field in the pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is a workaround, you can **add another column** with the below formula and add that column in pivot table as **Summarize values by Average**.

Formula: `=(SUMIF([Segment],[@Segment],[nr of visitors])/SUM([nr of visitors]))/(COUNTIF([Segment],[@Segment])/COUNTA([Organisation name]))`

**Screenshot below**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example! My initial dataset is different, see updated post.

Comment: Please check the updated answer above

Comment: Thanks, too bad it can't be done inside the pivot table. But I guess this will do. Thanks for your help!